# multiple sockets between server and client

Tags: java, sockets

I have a java server aplication which comunicate with multiple clients via `SocketChannel`. On this channel, client sends a request and server sends an answer. Now I want add feature that server can sends file to the client. I don't want send it via the socket whith I am using for comunication so is good idea to have more sockets between one client and one server? If yes how to handle them? Have I use something like this?

```
SocketChannel socket = serverSocket.accept()
if(!addressSet.contains(socket.address)) {
    it is comunicate socket
}
else {
    it is date transfer socket
}
```

or is there some better way?

Comment: You have to use same socket from which the client is connected. No matter its a data transfer socket or communicator socket.

Comment: But if a client creates two sockets it would be works? That I would choose which one to use to send a message or data. On the other hand, I realize that I cannot be 100% sure that two sockets with same IP is from same client (it can be router and two different clients)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new ServerSocket on a random port once you accept a client connection, then tell him that port number. He should then connect to that as the data connection. Then,have the server accept one connection from it, which better be from him, then close that ServerSocket. It's not foolproof but it's reasonably strong.

Comment: "Then,have the server accept one connection from it, which better be from him"

I'm a bit late but how do I check if it's the same client?

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a better way.
Use `ServerSocketChannel` and the method `public abstract SocketChannel accept() throws IOException`